# How to validate string is correct date time

Tags: c#, validation, datetime

I have some data picked up from an excel file.

I want to validate that the user has entered a valid date time string. I have tried to use DateTime.Parse method but found that certain values seem to be accepted.

For example,

If I submit 3.3 as a date time this is accepted by the DateTime.Parse method as a valid date time and outputs 03/03/2012 00:00:00

I want to want to block this. Only allowing the user to enter correctly formatted date times.

So for example a user could supply 03/03/2012 or 03/03/2012 12:30:00 but not values like 01022012 or 3.3.2012

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact`

This allows you do parse from a date format string of your choice.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx

Examples here:-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use RegEx to to this. Something like this should help @"\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}(\s+\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2})?"

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it on the client side with various jquery plugin/functions like [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/date) or a simple Google search can return many other useful results.

if you want to handle it on the server side, (I am not sure on what project you are working) but depending over it you can write your own method/use Regex or [Data Annotation MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs).

If you are still having trouble  try adding few details about your project such as Language, Architecture etc. that would help more in providing the right solution.

Hope it helps. Thankyou